# Application is not running

Tags: android, apk

I have created an android app in android studio.I have no errors and warnings and the BUILD is also succeeded. When it is installed in my phone the apk file gets installed, but it is not displayed in my applications list and so i cannot open the application.what is the problem?

Comment: check ur manifest file whether u added action and category for activity

Comment: 1- consider using meaningful title for the question, `not running` means something else. 2- search for intent-filter MAIN this need to be added in manifest for that activity

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're missing the following (intent-filter) in your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="#### YOUR MAIN ACTIVITY ####">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```